# Saving a list of dataframes into separate CSVs in R

Tags: r, tidyr, lapply, data-wrangling

I have a list of dataframes:

```
group_eg <- data.frame(
  CID = c(091, 091, 091, 091,
          101, 101, 101,
          102, 102, 102, 
          103, 103,
          104, 104, 104),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1091, 1091,
            1101, 1101, 1101,
            1102, 1102, 1102,
            1103, 1103,
            1104, 1104, 1104),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2091, 2091,
            2101, 2101, 2101, 
            2102, 2102, 2102,
            2103, 2103,
            2104, 2104, 2104),
  text = c("eg1", "eg2", "eg3", "eg3", 
           "eg4","eg5", "eg6", 
           "eg7", "eg8","eg9", 
           "eg10", "eg11", 
           "eg12", "eg13", "eg14")
)

group_eg_split <- split(group_eg, paste0("output_", ceiling(rleid(group_eg$CID)/2)))
```

I am trying to save each dataframe in the list to a separate CSV file with its corresponding name. This is what I have so far:

```
lapply(1:length(group_eg_split), function(i) write.csv(group_eg_split[[i]], 
                                                file = paste0(names(group_eg_split[i]), ".csv"),
                                                row.names = FALSE))
```

But it's returning a NULL value. How can I modify it?

Thank you!

Comment: Go check your directory, the CSV files should already be created (I successfully created three CSV files "output_1.csv" to "output_3.csv" in my directory using the code)

Comment: Try this `x <- write.csv(mtcars, file = "mtcars.csv")` and you can find that the `write.xxx()` functions is designed to return `NULL`. If you want the data frame to be returned, you can try `readr::write_csv()`, which returns the input invisibly.

Comment: package {rio}, a wrapper for numerous import/export libraries, has a dedicated function for this, `export_list()`: https://thomasleeper.com/rio/reference/export_list.html

Comment: You can replace lapply with forloop, then you won't see NULL values.

Comment: you might also use `invisible(lapply(...))`, this gives an additional hint that this call has side effects and it won't print anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct *ie* the dataframes are exported in csv. And it returns `NULL` because your function `write.csv()` returns `NULL`. If you don't wan't it, you can update your code and return what you want (the exported dataframes or just a message).

```
lapply(1:length(group_eg_split), 
       function(i){
           write.csv(
               group_eg_split[[i]],
               file = paste0(names(group_eg_split[i]), ".csv"),
               row.names = FALSE)
           return(group_eg_split[[i]])
       }
)
```

You can replace `return(...)` by `return(print("Export OK."))` if you prefer a message rather than the dataframes.